# Алгоритм сортировки выбором

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Я вычитал один алгоритм сортировки - сортировку выбором. И у меня возникло пару вопросов по поводу работы данного алгоритма.

Сам алгоритм:

```
def sort(seq):
    small = seq[0]
    index = 0
    for i in range(1,len(seq)):
        if seq[i] < small:
           small = seq[i]
           index = i
    return index

def sort2(seq):
    new_list = list()
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        small = sort(seq)
        new_list.append(seq.pop(small))
    return new_list

print(sort2([4,1,3,5,6]))
```

При использовании целого алгоритма сортировка проходит успешно. Однако, в процессе "разбора" алгоритма, я увидел что из первой функции возвращается только 1 по условию кода. Намечается вопрос, а как остальные части массива из первой попадают во вторую функцию, если по условию  может выводится только один элемент? Прошу простить мое непонимание возможно элементарных для Вас вещей, так как я начинающий в данном направлении) Заранее благодарю за ответы)

Comment: какая то непонятная сортировка. Вот [тут](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/) вроде более понятно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два списка - `seq` и `new_list`

На каждом шаге первая функция находит  и возвращает **индекс минимального элемента** из seq, причём с лишней работой, можно было бы ограничиться этим:

```
def sort(seq):
    index = 0
    for i in range(1,len(seq)):
        if seq[i] < seq[index]:
           index = i
    return index
```

Вторая функция **извлекает элемент c данным индексом** из `seq` и **добавляет** его в `new_list`

Выбор наименьшего - перекачка в новый список. Несколько отличается от того, как реализуется сортировка выбором в языках с массивами, но это всё равно сортировка выбором.

> из первой функции возвращается только 1 по условию кода.

Это не так. Умозрительно для данного примера последовательность индексов будет `1,1,0,0,0`, для других примеров  - другая

Comment: Тогда немного другой вопрос: разве тот индекс элемента и сам элемент, который выйдет первым, удаляется из родительского списка?  Куда он девается?

Comment: `seq.pop` же удаляет

Comment: Ой, какой я невнимательный. Прошу прощения, смотрел только на алгоритм в Вашем примере, а не на целый код. Большое спасибо за объяснение, теперь все встало на свои места)